# Whitespace rendering is confusing and does not preserve semantics

Tags: bug, editor, whitespace

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47052039/indentationerror-with-python) there is an indentation error. However, the error cannot be seen without entering the editor mode, since SO replaces the tabs with 4 spaces.

Syntactically, tabs in Python complete the indentation to 8 spaces, not 4. So the OP asks a question but SO replaced the broken code with a working one. I'm not sure how to fix it, but I think tabs should be rendered as tabs or as 8 spaces, at least in the context of Python code.

Comment: I agree, there should be someway to declare language with the code, and the code should be treat in context of that language. Including syntax highlighting etc.

Comment: Specifically in that question, the OP used this way: `<!-- language: lang-python -->`

Comment: The real [bug] here is Python, of course. But it seems that's a pretty popular language, so maybe our editor should work around it.